# Pool subpanel circuit correct?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, pool

I currently have a 200amp service feeding house including a 20amp 2 pole pool pump and a 60amp 2 pole pool heater/cooler, these circuits are not GFCI protected. I would like to replace the pool circuits with GFCI breakers as well as add a 50amp RV plug.

All single pole circuits have already been changed to tandems and I am out of space in panel. I think a sub panel is best, is there another option? If I do a sub panel is this circuit correct?

- 100amp breaker in main panel
- #4/4 AWG 5 feet to sub panel, sub panel neutral and ground not bonded
- 20 & 60amp GFCI breakers in sub panel feeding existing pool circuits moved to sub panel
- #4/4 AWG 12 feet to RV 50amp plug with one leg also feeding a 120v receptacle

All circuits have no neutral or grounds connected to any other circuit except the sub panel bus bars. am I correct, and is there anything I'm missing to make this up to code and safe? Thank you!

Comment: *#4/4 AWG 12 feet to RV 50amp plug with one leg also feeding a 110v plug* - uhm, not without a 15 or 20 amp breaker you didn't mention, you don't. Connecting a 120V 15-20A receptacle to a 50A breaker is a **definite** no-no.

Comment: Given it's all of 12 feet, just run a 20A breaker and 12 feet of 12/2 for your 120V receptacle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use any wire smaller than #3 CU 75°C wire feed a 100A subpanel.

You don't indicate wire type you are using for the 50A feed to the RV receptacle, UF cable would require #6 CU, using conduit and THWN would only require #8.

If you wan't to use one leg of the 240v branch circuit to the RV to feed a 120v receptacle you will need to provide overcurrent protection suitable for the receptacle. You can't just put a 15 or 20A receptacle on a 50A breaker.  For the short distance you describe a separate #12 feed might be easier. Easiest would be to buy an RV pedestal already has the breakers and receptacles in place https://amzn.to/3oP1zRQ .

Comment: I get now how stupid that was on the 120v plug. Thanks for wire size and panel suggestion